# Cache Eviction not working for Gemfire Partitioned regions

Tags: gemfire

I am using Pivotal cloud cache and have configured regions as Partitioned Regions.I am trying to use @Cache Evict from Spring data gemfire to evict the region data.It was working fine when the region type was Replicated and not working now.

Is there a way I can remove the data (key + values) from the Partitioned region using my client java application

Answer (score 0):

No matter which type of region you're using, `Eviction` should work. There are some caveats for `Partitioned Regions`, however, so you might want to have a look at [How Eviction Works](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/developing/eviction/how_eviction_works.html).
Regarding your second question, you can directly remove data from your java client application using several methods from the [`Region`](https://gemfire-98-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html) class, like `remove` and `delete`.

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: When trying for Partition regions I get below exception.  Org.apache.geode.cache .client.ServerOpertaionException.While performing a remote clear region.

Comment: The `clear` operation is not supported for `PARTITION` regions, please have a look at the [javadocs](https://gemfire-98-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#clear--) for more information.

Comment: I have tried the deleteById of GemfireRepository.It didnt work.

Comment: That's weird... are you sure you're using the correct `ID` and that `GemfireRepository` is correctly configured?.